# VBA Parameter object is improperly defined. Inconsistent or incomplete information was provided

Tags: vba, parameters, adodb

I have a problem as the topic. Run-error 3708 and my code break on append parameters line. Where I make a mistake? Table in oracle have only this 4 columns.

```
    Sub Export(path As String)

...

        Set insertCmnd = New ADODB.Command
        With insertCmnd
            .ActiveConnection = cn
            .CommandType = adCmdText
            .CommandText = "INSERT INTO DEVCRM.COK_WE_REZYGNACJA_KO (IMIĘ, NAZWISKO, PESEL, NAZWISKO_RODOWE_MATKI) " _
                + "VALUES(:IMIĘ,:NAZWISKO,:PESEL,:NAZWISKO_RODOWE_MATKI)"
            .Prepared = True
        End With

        Set prmpNAME = insertCmnd.CreateParameter(name:=":IMIĘ", Type:=adLongVarChar)
        Set prmpSURNAME = insertCmnd.CreateParameter(name:=":NAZWISKO", Type:=adLongVarChar)
        Set prmpPESEL = insertCmnd.CreateParameter(name:=":PESEL", Type:=adLongVarChar)
        Set prmpNRM = insertCmnd.CreateParameter(name:=":NAZWISKO_RODOWE_MATKI", Type:=adLongVarChar)

        With insertCmnd.Parameters
            .Append prmpNAME **here is a break**
            .Append prmpSURNAME
            .Append prmpPESEL
            .Append prmpNRM
        End With

        cn.BeginTrans
        Do Until excelRecords.EOF

            prmpNAME.Value = excelRecords.Fields("IMIĘ").Value
            prmpSURNAME.Value = excelRecords.Fields("NAZWISKO").Value
            prmpPESEL.Value = excelRecords.Fields("PESEL").Value
            prmpNRM.Value = excelRecords.Fields("NAZWISKO_RODOWE_MATKI").Value

            insertCmnd.Execute

            excelRecords.MoveNext
        Loop
        cn.CommitTrans
        cn.Close
    End Sub
```

Thanks for a help!

Answer (score 7):

You have to specify the `Size` parameter when calling `CreateParameter`.

The following doesn't cause error 3708 for me:

```
CreateParameter(name:=":IMIE;", Type:=adLongVarChar, Size:=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

When creating a parameter, ensure that the size defined in SQL is mentioned in the .CreateParameter("",adVarchar,***10***,value)